# Passing variables into function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to execute 2 sets of variables in my function  (in my functions.php)

EDIT - Here is the working code to apply header-show/header-hide class to one div (header)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


// adjust this number to select when your button appears on scroll-down
var offset = 70,

// bind with the button link
$animation = $('header');

// apply animation
$(window).scroll(function(){
    ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $animation.addClass('header-hide').removeClass("header-show"):
    $animation.addClass('header-show').removeClass("header-hide");
});

});
```

I wanted to reuse the code for a second div (#top-btn) but can't get it to work. What I have is below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    function reusuableAnimationFunc(elementName, offset, hideClass, showClass) {
    $animation = $(elementName);

    $(window).scroll(function(){
      ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $animation.addClass(hideClass).removeClass(showClass):
      $animation.addClass(showClass).removeClass(hideClass);
    });
  }

  reusuableAnimationFunc('header', 70, 'header-hide', 'header-show')
  reusuableAnimationFunc('#top-btn', 300, 'element-hide', 'element-show')

});
```

Not sure if it is written correctly or if I need to put part of it in my html. I just want to run the same function for two different divs

Comment: are you saying this code does not work ?

Comment: The code works when I apply the values in manually (header, 70, etc). I wanted to repeat the code for another div, so wanted to bring in the parameters dynamically. But I can't get it to work

Comment: what code did you use for the dynamic parameters ?

Comment: I just mean I didn't want to write the parameters (header-hide, etc) into the function but bring them in as variables so I can reuse the function

Comment: See my answer it accepts arrays for selectors: `var sel = ['#ID', '.class', 'tag', '[attribute]`]` and scroll distance `var dist = [20, 50, 70, 2]` and alternating classes `var on = 'on'` and `var off = 'off'`.

Comment: But it seems to animate as you scroll. I'm just looking to apply a class once user is at a specific spot, then it animates at its own pace (fade in/out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is not accessible outside of the jQuery.ready

Your function should be in the global scope. Therefore, you have to remove this "jQuery(document).ready(function($){...}".

Replace it with this:

```
function reusuableAnimationFunc(elementName, offset, hideClass, showClass) {
        $animation = $(elementName);

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ? $animation.addClass(hideClass).removeClass(showClass):
                $animation.addClass(showClass).removeClass(hideClass);
        });
    }

    reusuableAnimationFunc('header', 70, 'header-hide', 'header-show')
    reusuableAnimationFunc('#top-btn', 300, 'element-hide', 'element-show')
```

Comment: The code should work, I'll update the question with the original